# How to update datagridview row cell value?

Tags: c#, winforms

not sure if this is how it should be and if it does what should be the property after the Cells[0]?

the idea is to update the progress and other information in each row of the datagrid.
I'm using the winforms built in datagridview control.

I added the most details I can think of.

The problem is how to update.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Download_Multi_Files
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<FileDownload> listDownload = new List<FileDownload>();
        FileDownload fileURL = new FileDownload();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            fileURL.url = @"https://dl.teamviewer.com/download/version_15x/TeamViewer_Setup.exe";
            fileURL.progress = 0;
            fileURL.status = "Ready";
            fileURL.speed = "";
            fileURL.data = "";
            fileURL.filename = Path.GetFileName(fileURL.url);
            listDownload.Add(fileURL);

            var fileURL2 = new FileDownload();
            fileURL2.url = @"http://s3.amazonaws.com/calibrize/calibrize_2_setup.exe";
            fileURL2.progress = 0;
            fileURL2.data = "";
            fileURL2.speed = "";
            fileURL2.status = "Ready";
            fileURL2.filename = Path.GetFileName(fileURL2.url);
            listDownload.Add(fileURL2);

            var fileURL3 = new FileDownload();
            fileURL3.url = @"https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.9.0/node-v13.9.0-x64.msi";
            fileURL3.progress = 0;
            fileURL3.data = "";
            fileURL3.speed = "";
            fileURL3.status = "Ready";
            fileURL3.filename = Path.GetFileName(fileURL3.url);
            listDownload.Add(fileURL3);

            var fileURL4 = new FileDownload();
            fileURL4.url = @"https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/9/4/1949aa9c-6536-48f2-81fa-e7bb07410b36/SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe";
            fileURL4.progress = 0;
            fileURL4.data = "";
            fileURL4.speed = "";
            fileURL4.status = "Ready";
            fileURL4.filename = Path.GetFileName(fileURL4.url);
            listDownload.Add(fileURL4);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = listDownload;
        }

        private void UpdateProgressByRowHandle(int rowHandle, string column, string message)
        {
            dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].(rowHandle, column, message);
            }));
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public class FileDownload
        {
            public string url { get; set; }
            public int progress { get; set; }
            public string speed { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string filename { get; set; }
            public string data { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't touch the grid. the whole point of binding is that the grid reflects what's in the data source. You should be updating the `progress` of the appropriate `FileDownload` object and the grid will update itself. Because you're affecting the UI, that change has to be made on the UI thread, so you'll still need to use `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Why are you creating three `FileDownload` objects inside the constructor but the first one is assigned to a field for some reason? That first one is not special. There should be no field. they should all be created the same way. The idea would be that each download process would have a reference to the appropriate `FileDownload` object and be able to update it as the download progresses.